Rselenium - why am I not navigating to the correct path
I have loaded the RSelenium package and I am using the code below
  # Initialize RSelenium driver
  driver <- rsDriver(port=4444L, browser = "chrome", chromever = "latest", verbose = FALSE)
  remDr <- rD$client
 
  # Navigate
  remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")

It stops at Navigate with the following error
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

I was expecting this to flow through to the website so that I could automatically search

Try another browser like firefox
